# Vodafone usb Modem(ZTE K3770-z) is not working

Tags: usb-modem

I have purchased new vodafone usb modem (ZTE K3770-z) and  tried to  connect it with ubuntu 11.04. But it is not automatically detected on  ubuntu.

---

I have installed  windows 7 and ubuntu 11.04 on my laptop.

To detect the modem on ubuntu I did the following steps :-

1) Connect the modem with laptop and boot the machine with windows 7
2) After detecting the modem on wndows, restarted the machine and enter into ubuntu.

---

Does anyone know any solution to detect the modem automatically on ubuntu?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Comment: @blueXrider: why would you like to close this question?.. May i know the reason ?.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. No activity. No answers. http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2651/ask-ubuntu-clean-up

Comment: @blueXrider: Ok then close it. But I am still facing this issue. let me try on 12.04. if it is not working i will post another question. is that ok?..

Comment: It works in 13.10? or 12.04.4?

Answer (score 1):

open Synaptic Package Manager Type "Smartlink" into the search field in the Synaptic Package Manager and install all of smarlink package. http://www.ehow.com/how_5435902_install-modem-drivers-ubuntu.html#ixzz2BcaT8Ean it works with me very well

Answer (score 0):

eject your device from terminal or disks.

1)you can find disks at search of unity.click to the cd rom of your modem and at left top you could find a triangle above a line at the center of three options. it will say "eject the medium in the drive". click at here.

2)In terminal, type eject & press enter

you could find your modem at nm after 12 sec,

[click here to add your device id to usb switch mode for auto eject at startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487004/how-to-add-d-link-dwm-156-to-usb-switch-mode-for-automatic-eject-of-driver-cd)

for refreshing the network manager from terminal try the command,

sudo service network-manager restart

press enter and type your password that is, you can stop restarting of your computer or replugin of your modem

Answer (score -1):

Install usb-modeswitch:

sudo apt-get install usb-modeswitch

Comment: What is it? What does it do? Why is it necessary? Why would this solve the OPs issue? Add a bit more information to the answer please, it is recommended and important.

Comment: Explain more please

Answer (score -1):

May be late for you, but try this in your Windows 7 OS:

Go to **Device Manager** → **Universal Serial Bus Controller** → **Generic USB Hub** (right-click) → **Properties** → under **Power Management** tab, un-check "**Allow the computer to turn off dis device to save power**".

This may work.

Comment: and  try doing it for all devices under "Universal Serial Bus Controller"...